# Double icons in Applications list

Tags: android

I'm noticing that there are double icons for an application I recently built. Is this being caused by an issue in my manifest? Or is this an artifact from a previously deleted rev of the apk?

Comment: what do you call double icon?

Comment: Two icons in the Applications listing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you modified the package name once and Android installed the new version of your app under the new package name. You can just uninstall your old application then. :-)

Comment: Thanks for checking.. I confirmed that the application had been deleted. When it gets re-installed, two icons appear.

Comment: Okay, then I guess you have multiple activities defined in your manifest that should appear in the Launcher. ;-)